# How to trim and replace a string

Tags: regex, string, r

```
string<-c("       this is a string  ")
```

Is it possible to trim-off the white spaces on both the sides of the string (or just one side as required) and replace it with a desired character, such as this, in R? The number of white spaces differ on each side of the string and have to be retained on replacement.

```
"~~~~~~~this is a string~~"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like an inefficient way of doing it, but maybe you should be looking in the direction of `gregexpr` and `regmatches` instead of `gsub`:

```
x <- "    this is a string  "
pattern <- "^ +?\\b|\\b? +$"
startstop <- gsub(" ", "~", regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x))[[1]])
text <- paste(regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x), invert=TRUE)[[1]], collapse="")
paste0(startstop[1], text, startstop[2])
# [1] "~~~~this is a string~~"
```

And, for fun, as a function, and a "vectorized" function:

```
## The function
replaceEnds <- function(string) {
  pattern <- "^ +?\\b|\\b? +$"
  startstop <- gsub(" ", "~", regmatches(string, gregexpr(pattern, string))[[1]])
  text <- paste(regmatches(string, gregexpr(pattern, string), invert = TRUE)[[1]],
                collapse = "")
  paste0(startstop[1], text, startstop[2])
}

## use Vectorize here if you want to apply over a vector
vReplaceEnds <- Vectorize(replaceEnds)
```

Some sample data:

```
myStrings <- c("    Four at the start, 2 at the end  ", 
               "   three at the start, one at the end ")

vReplaceEnds(myStrings)
#        Four at the start, 2 at the end        three at the start, one at the end  
#  "~~~~Four at the start, 2 at the end~~" "~~~three at the start, one at the end~"
```

Comment: My actual data does require 'vectorize'. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jackson, you can use the same approach to "vectorize" Andrie's function too.

Comment: @jackson `gsub` *is* vectorised?

Comment: @SimonO101, yes--I'm sure yours takes the cake.

Comment: @SimonO101 failed to notice. Yours effectively has it all at one go.

Answer (score 6):

Use `gsub`:

```
gsub(" ", "~", "    this is a string  ")
[1] "~~~~this~is~a~string~~"
```

This function uses regular expressions to replace (i.e. sub), all occurrences of a pattern inside a string.

In your case, you have to express the pattern in a special way:

```
gsub("(^ *)|( *$)", "~~~", "    this is a string  ")
[1] "~~~this is a string~~~"
```

The pattern means:

- `(^ *)`: Find one or more spaces at the **start** of the string
- `( *$)`: Find one or more spaces at the **end** of the string
- `` `| ``: The OR operator

---

Now you can use this approach to tackle your problem of replacing each space with a new character:

```
txt <- "    this is a string  "
foo <- function(x, new="~"){
  lead <- gsub("(^ *).*", "\\1", x)
  last <- gsub(".*?( *$)", "\\1", x)
  mid  <- gsub("(^ *)|( *$)", "", x)
  paste0(
    gsub(" ", new, lead),
    mid,
    gsub(" ", new, last)
  )
}

> foo("    this is a string  ")
[1] "~~~~this is a string~~"

> foo(" And another one        ")
[1] "~And another one~~~~~~~~"
```

For more, see `?gsub` or `?regexp`.

Comment: This adds ~ to spaces between the words, too.

Comment: The white space is not symmetrical on both ends of the original string.

Comment: Not explicitly described in the question, but it seems that leading and lagging white space may differ in length and should be replaced by an appropriate number of ~

Comment: Sorry, the question missed a crucial point. The replacer(~) have to be same in number as that of the white spaces replaced on each sides of the string. I'm editing the question. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: I think this would be faster than my solution.

Answer (score 6):

Or using a more complex pattern matching and `gsub`...

```
gsub("\\s(?!\\b)|(?<=\\s)\\s(?=\\b)", "~", "    this is a string  " , perl = TRUE )
#[1] "~~~~this is a string~~"
```

Or with @AnandaMahto's data:

```
gsub("\\s(?!\\b)|(?<=\\s)\\s(?=\\b)", "~", myStrings , perl = TRUE )
#[1] "~~~~Four at the start, 2 at the end~~" 
#[2] "~~~three at the start, one at the end~"
```

#### Explanation

This uses the positive and negative lookahead and look behind assertions:

- `\\s(?!\\b)` - match a space, `\\s` not followed by a word boundary, `(?!\\b)`. This would work by itself for everything *except* the last space before the first word, i.e. by itself we would get
  `"~~~~ this is a string~~"`. So we need another pattern...
- `(?<=\\s)\\s(?=\\b)` - match a space, `\\s` that *is* preceded by another space, `(?<=\\s)` and  *is* followed by a word boundary, `(?=\\b)`.

And it is `gsub` so it tries to make the maximal number of matches that it can.

Comment: Your regex skills far outstrip mine. +1

Comment: @AnandaMahto I'm pretty sure I learnt about assertions from you! :-)